# PHP error when connecting to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I was trying to connect to my local database through the php code but I get this error:

> Syntax error, unexpected '$result' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ')'

and I don't understand where's the problem. Here's my code:

```
    <?php
    $hostname = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";

    $databaseName = "newspage";

    $dbConnected = @mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password);

    $dbSelected = @mysqli_connect($databaseName, $dbConnected);

    $query = "INSERT INTO news(titolo, testo, data)VALUES('".$_POST["titolo"]."', '".$_POST["testo"]."', NOW())";
    $result = @mysqli_query($query);
    if(!$result){
    echo("Errore aggiunta news: " . mysqli_error(mysqli $result));
    exit();
    }

    else {
    mysqli_close(mysqli $dbConnected);
    echo('News caricata!<br><a href="add.php">Clicca qui</a> per aggiungere altre news.<br><a href="edit.php">Clicca qui</a> per apportare modifiche alle news.<br><a href="../index.php">Clicca qui</a> per tornare alla pagina principale.'); 
    }
?>
```

Comment: Learn to use prepared statements instead of concatenating variables, to protect against SQL injection. And don't use `@` when you're still debugging.

Comment: Your second call to `mysqli_connect()` should be `mysqli_select_db()`, and the arguments are in the wrong order.

Comment: **WARNING**: Using the error-suppressing YOLO operator (`@`) obscures problems with your code and makes debugging issues like this a whole lot more complicated. That's a tool of last resort and should only be used in exceptional circumstances. You should display an error message for the user, log a problem, initiate some kind of retry, or all of these things in conjunction.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```
echo("Errore aggiunta news: " . mysqli_error(mysqli $result));
```

It should be:

```
echo("Errore aggiunta news: " . mysqli_error($result));
```

Comment: If I edit it I get this: Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given

Comment: That's because you are not running the query against any database.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass dbname too in `mysqli_connect`

```
$dbConnected = @mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $databaseName);
```

and to execute query.

```
$result = $dbConnected->query("select * from tablename");
```

Further your query should be:

```
    $query = "INSERT INTO news(titolo, testo, data) 
    VALUES('".$_POST['titolo']."', '".$_POST['testo']."', NOW())";
```

Comment: Neither of these is related to the syntax error being reported.

Comment: That query is in urgent need of placeholder values.